# A question on the paper by Littell and Folks (1971)

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics, asymptotics

I have been reading this very interesting paper but have come across something that I do not quite understand, namely how the asymptotic limit of the quantity $-\frac{1}{n} \log \left(1-F_n^{F} \left(\sqrt{n}t \right) \right)$ is derived.

[image]

where $T_n^{F}$ is a test statistic. I understand that under the mull hypothesis p-values are uniformly distributed in (0,1) and hence $-2\log\left( 1-F \left( T_n^{F} \right) \right)$ follows a chi squared distribution but does that come in handy here?

The result here must come from some approximation although none that I have tried led me to this.

All help is appreciated, thank you.

The paper is called "Asymptotic optimality of Fisher's Method of Combining Independent Tests" and I have only found in jstor:
http://www.jstor.org/stable/2284230?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: The "whole paper" is behind a pay wall unless you have access to www.jstor.org.

Comment: @NickCox You are right, I could not find a pdf version anywhere though.  I think the above is an application of Mill's ratio although I haven't got to the details yet.

Comment: I can't help except minutely: http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2006-08/msg00432.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably there is a much more straightforward way, but here is what I came up with:

According to the paper $F_n^{(F)}()$ is the cumulative distribution function of $T_n^{(F)}$. This last one is, as said, distributed as "the square root of a chi-square with $2P$ degrees of freedom". This is the [chi distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_distribution). Its cummulative distribution function is (for $2p$ degrees of freedom)

$$F_n^{(F)}(z) = \frac {\gamma (p, z^2/2)}{\Gamma (p)}$$

where $\gamma(\,,)$ is the lower incomplete gamma function, and $\Gamma ()$ is the Gamma function. Since $p$ is an integer, we have $\Gamma (p) = (p-1)!$

A series representation of the lower incomplete gamma function is

$$\gamma (p, z^2/2) = (p-1)!\cdot \left(1-e^{-z^2/2}\cdot\left[\sum_{m=0}^{p-1}\frac{(z^2/2)^m}{m!}\right]\right)$$

Then

$$1- F_n^{(F)}(z) = 1- \frac {(p-1)!\cdot \left(1-e^{-z^2/2}\cdot\left[\sum_{m=0}^{p-1}\frac{(z^2/2)^m}{m!}\right]\right)}{(p-1)!}$$

$$=e^{-z^2/2}\cdot\left[\sum_{m=0}^{p-1}\frac{(z^2/2)^m}{m!}\right]$$

So

$$-\frac {1}{n}\ln \big[1- F_n^{(F)}(\sqrt n t)\big] = \frac 12 \frac {nt^2}{n} - \frac {1}{n}\ln\left(\sum_{m=0}^{p-1}\frac{(nt^2/2)^m}{m!}\right)$$

$$= \frac 12 t^2 - \frac {1}{n}\ln\left(\frac{t^{2p-2}}{2^{p-1}\cdot (p-1)!}n^{p-1}+ o\left(n^{(p-1)}\right)\right)$$

The leading term in the sum inside the logarithm is $O\left(n^{(p-1)}\right)$ so

$$\ln\left[O\left(n^{(p-1)}\right)\right] = O(\ln n)$$

(add and subtract to the whole expression $(1/n)\ln(n^{p-1})$ to see what happens)

Divided by $n$ it goes to zero as $n\rightarrow \infty$ (that's why the whole expression is written in the paper as $o(1)$, because it goes to zero on its own), and so

$$-\frac {1}{n}\ln \big[1- F_n^{(F)}(\sqrt n t)\big] \rightarrow \frac 12 t^2,\;\;\; n \rightarrow \infty$$

Comment: Thank you Alecos, I figured it out a while back, your answer is much appreciated nevertheless.

Comment: @JohnK You're welcome. Did you figure it out through some other approach? If yes, it would be nice to share. Mine is too "primitive" I would say.